# I have a Ruby array of objects, how to change this array into multiple arrays based on the property of those objects?

Tags: ruby, arrays, algorithm

What's the best way to change a big array into multiple sub arrays based on the property of the objects in the original array? For example I have an array of objects(all objects have the same properties):

```
array = [
    {:name => "Jim", :amount => "20"},
    {:name => "Jim", :amount => "40"},
    {:name => "Jim", :amount => "30"},
    {:name => "Eddie", :amount => "7"},
    {:name => "Eddie", :amount => "12"},
    {:name => "Pony", :amount => "330"},
    {:name => "Pony", :amount => "220"},
    {:name => "Pony", :amount => "50"}
]
```

Note that all objects with the same *name* property are consecutive in the array. Now I want to group the objects into sub arrays based on the name property. What I need is:

```
result = [
    [
        {:name => "Jim", :amount => "20"},
        {:name => "Jim", :amount => "40"},
        {:name => "Jim", :amount => "30"}
    ],
    [
        {:name => "Eddie", :amount => "7"},
        {:name => "Eddie", :amount => "12"}
    ],
    [
        {:name => "Pony", :amount => "330"},
        {:name => "Pony", :amount => "220"},
        {:name => "Pony", :amount => "50"}
    ]
]
```

What's the best way to do this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use [`group_by`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by) for the heavy lifting and then [`map`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-map) to pull out what you want:

```
result = array.group_by { |h| h[:name] }.map { |k, v| v }
```

For example:

```
>> results = array.group_by { |h| h[:name] }.map { |k, v| v }
>> pp results
[[{:name=>"Jim", :amount=>"20"},
  {:name=>"Jim", :amount=>"40"},
  {:name=>"Jim", :amount=>"30"}],
 [{:name=>"Eddie", :amount=>"7"},
  {:name=>"Eddie", :amount=>"12"}],
 [{:name=>"Pony", :amount=>"330"},
  {:name=>"Pony", :amount=>"220"},
  {:name=>"Pony", :amount=>"50"}]]
```

You could also skip the `map` and go straight to [`Hash#values`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Hash.html#method-i-values):

```
result = array.group_by { |h| h[:name] }.values
```

Thanks go to [KandadaBoggu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/163203/kandadaboggu) for pointing out this oversight.

Comment: Probably you can shorten this further by calling `values` on the `group_by` result, i.e. `array.group_by{ |h| h[:name] }.values`

Comment: @KandadaBoggu: Yeah, that would work and I'm a little embarrassed that I didn't see that first.

Answer (score 2):

If hashes with the same `:name` value are always consecutive elements you can do it like that:

```
result = array.each_with_object([]) do |e, memo|
  if memo.last && memo.last.last[:name] == e[:name]
    memo.last << e
  else
    memo << [e] 
  end 
end
```

or you can use [`Enumerable#chunk`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-chunk) (again, taking into account that elements with the same `:name` value are consecutive):

```
result = array.chunk{ |e| e[:name] }.map(&:last)
```

Comment: Beware that pre 1.9 Ruby, hashes are not guaranteed to be in a given order. So in that case, there wouldn't be such a thing as "always consecutive".

Comment: You're right, but in this particular case we're iteration over an array and hashes are just happened to be its elements. So there is nothing to worry about. I believe arrays were ordered even in the very first release of Ruby =)

Comment: ah, yes! an array of hashes - sorry :-)